# TypeError received while trying to create Folium Colorline

Tags: python, leaflet, geolocation, gis, folium

I'm trying to create ColorLine for set of latitude and longitude coordinates. Code for the same is below,

```
map_object = folium.Map(location=[15.235683, 75.167737], zoom_control=True, zoom_start = 10, control_scale=True)
coordinates = [(15.564746,74.819551), (15.392602,75.173812),(15.392602,75.173812),(15.413797,74.735791)]
color=['red','green','blue']  # should be of length len(coordinates) -1
line = features.ColorLine(coordinates,colors = color , weight= 10)
line.add_to(map_object)
```

But on execution, am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<xxx>\Interactive maps\main.py", line 12, in <module>       
    line = features.ColorLine(coordinates,colors = color , weight= 10)
  File "<xxx>\Python39\lib\site-packages\folium\features.py", line 1892, in __init__
    if colormap is None:
  File "<xxx>\Python39\lib\site-packages\branca\colormap.py", line 235, in __init__
    self.index = [vmin + (vmax-vmin)*i*1./(n-1) for i in range(n)]
  File "<xxx>\Python39\lib\site-packages\branca\colormap.py", line 235, in <listcomp>
    self.index = [vmin + (vmax-vmin)*i*1./(n-1) for i in range(n)]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

I understood that vmin and vmax are string and '-' is not supported for strings. But how to resolve this. Is this a bug at folium package?

Tried modifying the value of `colors` to string and list of strings.

Expected:

```
colors : list-like object with at least two colors.
...
...
* a color name or shortcut (e.g: `"y"` or `"yellow"`)
```

Since in colormap.py-> class LinearColormap has this detailed, I expected passing string values of color should get handled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`folium.features`'s `ColorLine` doesn't accept `str` for colors, but we can input RGB values using a `for` `loop`:

```
for color in [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]:
    features.ColorLine(coordinates, colors=color, weight=10).add_to(map_object)
```

[image]

There is more control over the colors with `colormap` than `colors`, and specifying both `folium` will ignore `colors`; however, if we draw more `coordinates` (with different `weight`s to make it more obvious), it seems `folium` maxes out at 2 colors:

```
coordinates = [[15.564746,74.819551], [15.392602,75.253812],[15.392702,75.193812],[15.413797,74.785791],[15.452702,75.103812],[15.473797,74.985791]]
color = [[1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]]
for index, _color in enumerate(['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow']):
    features.ColorLine(coordinates[index:], colors=color[index], colormap=[[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]], weight=index + 4).add_to(map_object)
```

[image]

We can `enumerate` coordinates and give that to `colors` instead of a `list` of colors, but then it only takes the first color and ignores the rest:

```
for index, _color in enumerate(coordinates):
    features.ColorLine(coordinates[index:], colors=_color, colormap=[[1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], weight=index + 4).add_to(map_object)
```

[image]

Maybe I need to play around with `features.ColorLine` more but yes it isn't very flexible. The number of colors that can be added seems to max out at two (i.e. first and last colors, ignores the rest), though you can draw as many lines as you want (using those two colors).

Comment: are these documented anywhere? or you tried things out and found out. because I see documentation for almost all classes of the folium package. but still it seems to be not complete and missed out in few places like this ColorLine!!

Comment: @Jose25X mostly from https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html